# Pathfinder golem senses / sight

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I cannot find a particular documentation about golem senses, what will happen when a golem is inside a Fog cloud spell? Can he see and hear normally? Is its line of sight blocked?
In our case we are dealing with an Iron golem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Golems are constructs.  Per [the general construct rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct) (unless the specific golem writeup overrides it) they therefore have darkvision 60' and low-light vision.

I'm not sure how you are not finding this, as it's in the stat block for every creature under Senses, right after the Init in the top section of the monster stats. For example:

```
Iron Golem  CR 13
XP 25,600
N Large construct
Init –1; Senses darkvision 60 ft., low-light vision; Perception +0
```

They also have immunity to mind-affecting affects including illusions of the pattern and phantasm types, and immunity to spells in general, but *[fog cloud](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fog-cloud)* is a SR/no conjuration (creation) spell and thus the fog it conjures blocks sight. (Because "An iron golem is immune to spells or spell-like abilities that allow spell resistance.")

So no, an iron golem can not see through a *fog cloud* (and it can slip on *grease*). Those are actually some of the basic standbys to fight them.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but no description about their senses: can they hear? They see normally with 2 eyes like humanoid creatures (with darkvision of course)? Or they see at 360°? (I hardly figure out they can smell or taste but.. who knows)